# Ip address keeps reverting back to the wrong one

Tags: debian, networking, ip

I had set up a Debian server with an IP address that was assigned to another device by accident. I forced the server to connect through `/etc/network/interfaces` but am still finding it switches to the original IP address and I am unable to find the original network configuration file.

The interim fix is to change the `/etc/network/interfaces` to its original device of `ens192` but the device is currently `eth0`, and change it back to its current device and reboot.

Comment: Maybe you set up the interface in NetworkManager to override the (ancient) /etc/network/interfaces setting? I'd remove the complete entry about your network device from /etc/network/interfaces and make sure NetworkManager sets up the right address.

Comment: Are you using Network Manager?